# PHP DomDocument not formatting correctly

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, xml-formatting

I am trying to make my PHP update an existing XML-file, but it doesn't work completely as it suppost to. The PHP-code suppose to add a childnode with elements within the root-element of the xml-file. But somehow the formatting is not working correctly and it puts all the newly added xml-elements in one line.
If i remove the lastChild-option from the php it puts the newly added xml-elements outside the root but formats the xml correct.

Example existing XML-file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <root>
          <testing>
            <test>test</test>
            <test1>test1</test1>
            <test2>test2</test2>
            <test3>test3</test3>
          </testing>
          <testing>
            <test>test</test>
            <test1>test1</test1>
            <test2>test2</test2>
            <test3>test3</test3>
          </testing>
          <testing>
            <test>test</test>
            <test1>test1</test1>
            <test2>test2</test2>
            <test3>test3</test3>
          </testing>
    </root>
```

Example PHP-code:

```
$file = 'DEFAULT_DATE_CONVERSION4.xml';
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load($file);
$xml2 = $xml->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('datetimes');

    $app = $xml->createElement('testing');
    $testtext = "test";
    $app->appendChild($xml->createElement('test', $testtext));
    $app->appendChild($xml->createElement('test1', $testtext));
    $app->appendChild($xml->createElement('test2', $testtext));
    $app->appendChild($xml->createElement('test3', $testtext));
    $xml->lastChild->appendChild($app);

$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->saveXML();        
$xml->save("test.xml");
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <testing>
    <test>test</test>
    <test1>test1</test1>
    <test2>test2</test2>
    <test3>test3</test3>
  </testing>
  <testing>
    <test>test</test>
    <test1>test1</test1>
    <test2>test2</test2>
    <test3>test3</test3>
  </testing>
  <testing>
    <test>test</test>
    <test1>test1</test1>
    <test2>test2</test2>
    <test3>test3</test3>
  </testing>
<testing><test>test</test><test1>test</test1><test2>test</test2><test3>test</test3></testing></root>
```

Expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datetimes>
  <testing>
    <test>test</test>
    <test1>test1</test1>
    <test2>test2</test2>
    <test3>test3</test3>
  </testing>
  <testing>
    <test>test</test>
    <test1>test1</test1>
    <test2>test2</test2>
    <test3>test3</test3>
  </testing>
  <testing>
    <test>test</test>
    <test1>test1</test1>
    <test2>test2</test2>
    <test3>test3</test3>
  </testing>
  <testing>
    <test>test</test>
    <test1>test</test1>
    <test2>test</test2>
    <test3>test</test3>
  </testing>
</datetimes>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get what your after by flagging to not preserve whitespace (`preserveWhiteSpace`) and then setting to format output (`formatOutput`)  when loading the document...

```
$file = 'DEFAULT_DATE_CONVERSION4.xml';
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$xml->load($file);

$app = $xml->createElement('testing');
$testtext = "test";
$app->appendChild($xml->createElement('test', $testtext));
$app->appendChild($xml->createElement('test1', $testtext));
$app->appendChild($xml->createElement('test2', $testtext));
$app->appendChild($xml->createElement('test3', $testtext));
$xml->lastChild->appendChild($app);

$xml->save("test.xml");
```

Comment: Thank you! You are my hero! Your solution worked perfectly!